# 'AttributeError: module '__main__' has no attribute '__package__'

Tags: python, flask, deployment, web-deployment, flask-restful

I was trying to build flask-web API. When I am trying to run the app.py code, I have got this error, please refer the code which I have mentioned below. Do I have to install some package to get '**package**' into '**main**'?

I tried to run in different platforms such jupyter notebook, spyder and Google Colab too, but it didn't work, and getting similar issues.

## Here is my app.py code whic is giving error:

```
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify, render_template
import pickle

app = Flask(__name__)
model = pickle.load(open('model.pkl', 'rb'))

@app.route('/')
def home():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/predict',methods=['POST'])
def predict():
    '''
    For rendering results on HTML GUI
    '''
    int_features = [int(x) for x in request.form.values()]
    final_features = [np.array(int_features)]
    prediction = model.predict(final_features)

    output = round(prediction[0], 2)

    return render_template('index.html', prediction_text='Employee Salary should be $ {}'.format(output))

@app.route('/predict_api',methods=['POST'])
def predict_api():
    '''
    For direct API calls trought request
    '''
    data = request.get_json(force=True)
    prediction = model.predict([np.array(list(data.values()))])

    output = prediction[0]
    return jsonify(output)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

## Here is the error message I have got:

```
* Serving Flask app "__main__" (lazy loading)
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: on
 * Restarting with stat
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-21-3add8626fce0>", line 36, in <module>
    app.run(debug=True)

  File "C:\Users\ishwo\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 990, in run
    run_simple(host, port, self, **options)

  File "C:\Users\ishwo\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\serving.py", line 1007, in run_simple
    run_with_reloader(inner, extra_files, reloader_interval, reloader_type)

  File "C:\Users\ishwo\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\_reloader.py", line 332, in run_with_reloader
    sys.exit(reloader.restart_with_reloader())

  File "C:\Users\ishwo\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\_reloader.py", line 159, in restart_with_reloader
    args = _get_args_for_reloading()

  File "C:\Users\ishwo\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\_reloader.py", line 76, in _get_args_for_reloading
    if __main__.__package__ is None:

AttributeError: module '__main__' has no attribute '__package__'}
```

Comment: Can you show your app.py code.

Comment: Sure, Satish. I have mentioned above in the problem statement by editing the post, kindly check.